# Ubuntu Server 14.04 -- how to install Sun Grid Engine?

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to search around a tutorial to install Sun Grid Engine on Ubuntu Server 14.04 without much success.

I came to this article, but got into the error such as:
http://www.socher.org/index.php/Main/HowToInstallSunGridEngineOnUbuntu

```
sudo qmon
Warning: Cannot convert string "intro" to type Pixmap

sudo sge_execd
error: communication error for "localhost/execd/1" running on port 6445: "can't bind socket"
```

Did Ubuntu still support this package? Or there is other better alternatives?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the source code here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gridscheduler/files/
and now decompress it then build it. If you arent familiar with how to do that which you probably are just enter the terminal and type `tar -zxvf /path/to/file` and then follow the instructions in the decompressed file. They can be found under GE2011.11p1/source/README.BUILD when decompressed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have a detailed instruction how to install this? I have a hard time in following it.